# Return Coordinates of Address with Apple Maps on Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, apple-maps

I would like to use terminal (or applescript) to get the lat and long of an address. Is this possible on OS X Mavericks now that there is an Apple Maps app in OS X?

Comment: Maps.app stores it's recent locations, the bookmarks and more in it's defaults. You can see them with "defaults read com.apple.Maps". That's really all I know.

Comment: You get the impression that they will be adding more AS support to maps.app, because for now, it includes a nicely done scripting dictionary with all the starter categories, but no real functionality for searching for a new location or getting properties of the current selected location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the Google Maps API instead:

`curl -sG --data-urlencode 'address=1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW Washington DC' 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false'|jq '.results[0].geometry.location[]'`

You can install [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) with `brew install jq`. Or replace the `jq` command with `awk '/^ *"lat"/{print $3;getline;print $3;exit}'`.

Comment: This works like a charm. However, Google has usage limits and I will need to make millions of calls. Do you know if there is similar functionality in Open Street Maps?

Answer (score 0):

> Maps.app stores it's recent locations, the bookmarks and more in it's
> defaults.

Thank you, sir! At least we can get the location of the current the window center:

```
#!/bin/bash
myLat=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print LastClosedWindowViewport:CenterLatitude" ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Maps.plist )
myLon=$( /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print LastClosedWindowViewport:CenterLongitude" ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Maps.plist )
echo ${myLat},${myLon}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).